# difficult type in swift

Tags: swift, struct, enums, tuples

I'm trying to make a 'Difficulty' type that can takes 3 states : easy, medium or hard. Then a 'minimum' and 'maximum' values will be set automatically and reachable like "myDifficultyInstance.min" or what.

I tried this but doesn't work, I get errors :

```
enum Difficulty {
   case easy(min: 50, max: 200)
   case medium(min: 200, max: 500)
   case hard(min: 500, max: 1000)
}
```

Then I tried with a struct but it becomes too weird and ugly.

Is there a simple solution to do that ?

Comment: You can find many examples in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Comment: Thanks, I check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you accepted an answer already, but if you want to have both preset and customizable difficulty setting i'd suggest doing it like that:

```
enum Difficulty {
   case easy
   case medium
   case hard
   case custom(min: Int, max: Int)

   var min : Int {
       switch self {
       case .easy:
           return 50
       case .medium:
           return 200
       case .hard:
           return 500
       case .custom(let min,_):
           return min
       }
   }

   var max : Int {
       switch self {
       case .easy:
           return 200
       case .medium:
           return 500
       case .hard:
           return 1000
       case .custom(_,let max):
           return max
       }
   }
}
```

This way you're getting enumerated difficulties (finite exclusive states) with an option to define a custom one.

Usage:

```
let difficulty : Difficulty = .easy
let customDifficulty : Difficulty = .custom(min: 70, max: 240)

let easyMin = difficulty.min
let easyMax = difficulty.max

let customMin = customDifficulty.min
let customMax = customDifficulty.max
```

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect too !

Answer (score 3):

> Default arguments are not allowed in enum cases

When you defining cases of `enum`, you can't define default values. Imagine it as you're just creating "patterns".

But what you can to is, that you can create default cases by creating static constants

```
enum Difficulty {
    case easy(min: Int, max: Int)
    case medium(min: Int, max: Int)
    case hard(min: Int, max: Int)

    static let defaultEasy = easy(min: 50, max: 200)
    static let defaultMedium = medium(min: 200, max: 500)
    static let defaultHard = hard(min: 500, max: 1000)
}
```

then you can use it like this

```
Difficulty.defaultEasy
Difficulty.defaultMedium
Difficulty.defaultHard
```

---

Also I think that for your case when you need to get *min* or *max* value, would be better if you were using custom data model

```
struct Difficulty {

    var min: Int
    var max: Int

    static let easy = Difficulty(min: 50, max: 200)
    static let medium = Difficulty(min: 200, max: 500)
    static let hard = Difficulty(min: 500, max: 1000) 
}
```

Comment: Nice solution!  #recursiveEnumerations ;)

Comment: Nice ! Then if I want to access the minimum value for exemple, how can I do ?

Comment: @Placard I'm not sure if you can do this with enums but better would be if you were using custom model `Difficulty`

Comment: @Placard updated my answer, you can inspire yourself

Comment: Perfect, it's exactly what I want ! Thanks